# 'No module' error for my own function despite having same directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, compiler-errors, python-import

I am writing a script file in the Jupyter notebook & I need to call a function. I created another file called myfunctions.py and defined my function called give_ans() there. I will have many more functions here later. But I get an error in the main script file when I use the following command

```
from myfunctions import give_ans
```

The error is **No module named 'myfunctions'**. I use pwd to see their path and it is exactly the same which is *'C:\Users\my name\OneDrive\my_code'*. So I don't know what is the cause of this error. Please advise. I have always been a Matlab coder and this is my first attempt here.

**Update: I found the problem & fixed it. I gave the solution in my answer below.**

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going wrong. Both of my Jupyter files are of the .ipynb extension whereas the myfunctions.ipynb script that I intend to import should be in .py form. To do so, I went to the command window (Anaconda one in my case), went to the same directory as mentioned in the question, and did the following.

```
pip install ipynb-py-convert
jupyter nbconvert --to python myfunctions.ipynb
```

This produced a .py file and then there was no error upon using the import statements as I wrote in the question.

**Edit:** Anyone reading this answer please also make sure to read the comments below.

Comment: In case you aren't looking to convert the notebook every time because it is still somewhat in the development stage or you don't want two files to track, there's importnb and ipynb that can be used to import from a notebook. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/import-jupyter-notebook-script-into-a-python-script/11747/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/package-for-importing-jupyter-notebooks-as-modules/12923/2?u=fomightez).

Comment: And if you are happy with having a notebook and a script, [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext#paired-notebooks) could perhaps be used to allow you easily automate the pairing of the notebook and the python script version.When you update the notebook, the script will be updated to keep it sync'd.

Comment: @wayne thanks for the response, In fact, just now I experienced what you mentioned. I had added another function and the import threw an error. So I had to repeat my answer process and was thinking I can't be doing this every time. And you gave the answer! I will go through the links. And will do as you said in your next comment.